# ext js 4 reuse grid in MVC, rows dissapear

Tags: extjs, grid, store

I have a problem in my ext JS applicatiom. Use MVC architecture:

```
    Ext.define('ME.controller.Stocks', {
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    models:[
        'Logs'
    ],
    stores:[

        'Logs'

    ],
    views:[
        'portal.portalItems.logGridPanel.LogGridPanel',
        'portal.portalItems.logGridPanel.LogGrid',
        'portal.PortalPanel',
        'portal.PortalDropZone',
        'portal.PortalColumn',
        'portal.Portlet',
        'portal.portalItems.base.Panel',  
    ]
});
```

Component with name 'LogGrid' adds to viewport dynamically. Its initcomponent function looks like:

```
initComponent: function()
    {
        var me=this;
var store=  Ext.create('ME.store.Logs', {
            storeId:Utils.formUID(LOGS_GRID.LOGS_STORE_ID, me[FIELDS_MAPPER.BASE_PANEL.CLIENTSIDE_GUID]),
            sorters:[
                {
                    property:FIELDS_MAPPER.LOGS_GRID.LOG_DATE,
                    direction:'DESC'
                }
            ]
        });
        this.store=store;
        this.columns=[
        {
            text:Message.get('console.portal.logGrid.DateHeaderText'),
            dataIndex:FIELDS_MAPPER.LOGS_MODEL.LOG_DATE,
            renderer:Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i:s<br>d.m.Y')
        },
        {
            text:Message.get('console.portal.logGrid.DepartmentHeaderText'),
            dataIndex:FIELDS_MAPPER.LOGS_MODEL.DEPARTMENT_NAME

        },
        {
            text:Message.get('console.portal.logGrid.ProtectionSystemsHeaderText'),
            dataIndex:FIELDS_MAPPER.LOGS_MODEL.PROTECTION_SYSTEM_NAME
        },
        {
            text:Message.get('console.portal.logGrid.PlanHeaderText'),
            dataIndex:FIELDS_MAPPER.LOGS_MODEL.PLAN_NAME
        },
        {
            text:Message.get('console.portal.logGrid.SourceHeaderText'),
            dataIndex:FIELDS_MAPPER.LOGS_MODEL.SECTION_NAME
        },
        {
            text:Message.get('console.portal.logGrid.MessageTextHeaderText'),
            dataIndex:FIELDS_MAPPER.LOGS_MODEL.EVENT_TYPE_NAME,
            minWidth:200
        },
        {
            dataIndex:FIELDS_MAPPER.LOGS_MODEL.EVENT_STATE_NAME,
            text:Message.get('console.portal.logGrid.StateHeaderText')
            //  renderer:changeStateColor
        }
    ];

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
```

Logs store is:

```
Ext.define('ME.store.Logs', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'ME.model.Logs',
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:URLS.JOURNAL_CONTROLLER,
        extraParams:{action:'getEvents'},
        actionMethods:{
            read:'POST'
        },
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            idProperty:FIELDS_MAPPER.LOGS_GRID.LOG_ID
        },
        autoLoad:false
    },
    pageSize:LOGS_GRID.ITEMS_PER_PAGE
});
```

PROBLEM IS:

When I have one instance of grid,  everything OK, but when I add new instance of grid,  rows (selection model)  dissapears from both grids. Such bug appears also  when I collapse grids. 
If it will be useful, grid component is situated in different panels.

And also I saw such thing:
When I create LogsGrid in one container with grid that uses different store, such bug appears too, but now rows from logGrid moves to another grid.. I don't know what to do.. Second day can't find an answer

Comment: do the stores have different storeId's ?

Comment: @nscrob You can use a store in as many grids as you like, it won't break. Bit I am not quite sure if posted all necessary code. Does your grids have the same Id or do you reuse any other instance within the grid? (except the store)

Comment: @user1580224 btw, I recommend you to let the ExtJS controller handle your store registration which is done when you list it within the controller store array. Note that you need to define it before doing so!

Comment: Note: Configuring two separate components using the same storeId means each component will be employing the same store instance. So, a change to the store in grid A will reflect in grid B. Seems rather like your problem, and for the selection model dissapear, I had a similar problem caused because the stores were out of sync, meaning modified(selected) are dirty records and are not commited to the store.

Comment: Yes you are totally right but I think me too. (OK, I must admit I never tried to register the same storeId twice and so I don'T know what will happen) But I guess we can just guess till there are more information :)

Comment: StoreId forms within custom parameter which I pass to the grid on it initialization: storeId= 'Logs-'+Ext.id(). That's why I am sure that each grid has different storeId